# What is a "Failed to load module "module-ladspa-sink"" error?

Tags: pulseaudio

When I put in the terminal pulseaudio appears:

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-ladspa-sink.c: Master sink not found
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-ladspa-sink" (argument: "sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=3.0,3.0,7.3,7.0,3.0,-1.0,-6.6,-6.3,-4.5,-4.0,1.1,1.2,5.8,7.9,8.8"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failure to start the daemon.
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: did you remove any modules? like the equalizer? If so: please check if the answer works for you to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found this [blog](http://turriebuntu.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/sound-issue-after-removing-pulseaudio-equalizer/) post with the same error  and an explanation:

> A few days ago I started having issues with the equalizer that is, no sound. I removed the equalizer as well as `ladspa-sdk`. I promptly forgot about the whole thing until I rebooted and my machine began running super slow. Checking in syslog I found stuff like this:

```
pulseaudio[3662]: module-ladspa-sink.c: Failed to load LADSPA plugin: file not found
pulseaudio[3662]: module.c: Failed to load module “module-ladspa-sink” (argument: “sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-stereo plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,2.5,2.5,0.0,0.0″): initialization failed.
pulseaudio[3662]: main.c: Module load failed.
Failed to initialize daemon.
pulseaudio[3660]: main.c: Daemon startup failed
```

> Clearly the equalizer had left something behind when I removed it. Turned out the problem was in `~/.pulse/default.pa`. The file had been modified in the install and not removed with it. The offending lines were at the end of the file. They looked like:

```
### Generated from: pulseaudio-equalizer
load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master=alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-stereo plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq #control=-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,2.5,2.5,0.0,0.0
set-default-sink ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq
set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-stereo 65536
set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-stereo 0
### END: Equalized audio configuration
```

> I commented out all lines shown by adding a # at the beginning of each line and saved the file. Problem solved.

---

So in short:

```
sudo nano ~/.pulse/default.pa
```

scroll down to the line shown in the quote and add a **#** in front of all the lines. Save and exit.

In newer versions, this file could also be at `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`.

Comment: Thank you so much Jorge Castro and Rinzwind, editing conkys I know that if I put #, override any instruction line, is awesome it, How  override the instruction lines of: module-ladspa-sink.c: Master sink not found; all works again. How works it, why just override this wrong instruction lines everything can be solved

Comment: Thanks, I added the new location, because `~/.pulse` didn't exist in my home folder.

Comment: Step 1 from [Ubuntu sound troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) apparently would work as well, but this is a more delicate way to handle this. Great solution, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

By a distro upgrade I had a corrupt pulseaudio configuration in my home folder in the `~/.config/pulse` folder, receiving the same errors as you. I just moved the complete folder into a backup folder. Pulseaudio immediately created a new fresh config folder by its autospawn function. I had sound again! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @rinzwind's answer (remove or comment out the lines about ladspa), run `pulseaudio-equalizer` to regerate configuration.

The overall problem is caused, probably, by the audio card replacement or other changes in hardware (that caused itself the changes in PCI address of audio card). I faced the same problem when put my HDD with Ubuntu into another laptop, but did the steps above and this made a trick.

Answer (score 0):

Its better you should use `pulseaudio-equalizer` and run this command :

`pulseaudio-equalizer enable`

This makes the auido profiles to come back.

Answer (score 0):

Just writing in to say that Rinzwind's answer still worked for me in 2019 after installing pulseaudioequalizer messed something up. I had to uninstall it first but then deleting the config folder and restarting my computer did the trick.