# No sound on Ubuntu 12.04 after using headphones

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones

I have a Hewlett Packard laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I used USB headphones, and had to manually mute the sound of main speakers in Sound settings. After I pulled them out and rebooted laptop (after a common glitch of monitor not turning on after sleep mode), the output devices list in Sound settings is empty.

Rebooting the laptop didn't help, nothing changed. Plugging back in the USB headphones also changed nothing, and no sound was in them either. I tried running commands google search suggested (with headphones plugged in). The results are:

```
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ pacmd No PulseAudio daemon running, or not
running as session daemon. liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ aplay
/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav ALSA lib
pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave aplay:
main:682: audio open error: No such file or directory
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ sudo aplay -l [sudo] password for liliet: 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** Home directory /home/liliet not ours. card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3:
HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]   Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 1:
Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC
Analog]   Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 2:
Prestigio [Prestigio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]   Subdevices:
1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ lspci -v |
grep -A7 -i "audio" 00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company
Device 1885     Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42   Memory
at f0344000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]   Capabilities:
<access denied  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel     Kernel modules:
snd-hda-intel

-- 00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1885
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16  Memory at
f0340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  Capabilities: <access
denied  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel     Kernel modules:
snd-hda-intel

liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ sudo aptitude --purge reinstall
linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r`
linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2 sudo: aptitude: command not
found liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ speaker-test -c 6 -D
'surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0'

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 Stream parameters are
48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels Using 16 octaves of pink noise ALSA lib
confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card 'PCH' ALSA lib
conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver
returned error: No such device ALSA lib
confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings ALSA lib
conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned
error: No such device ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error
evaluating name ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function
snd_func_refer returned error: No such device ALSA lib
conf.c:4720:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such device ALSA
lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 Playback open error: -19,No such device
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ speaker-test -c 6 -D
'surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0'

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 Stream parameters are
48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels Using 16 octaves of pink noise ALSA lib
confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card 'PCH' ALSA lib
conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver
returned error: No such device ALSA lib
confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings ALSA lib
conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned
error: No such device ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error
evaluating name ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function
snd_func_refer returned error: No such device ALSA lib
conf.c:4720:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such device ALSA
lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 Playback open error: -19,No such device
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ alsa force-reload mkdir: cannot create
directory `/var/run/alsa': Permission denied /sbin/alsa: Warning:
Failed to create /var/run/alsa/.  /sbin/alsa: Warning: Not keeping
list of removed modules because /var/run/alsa is absent. It will not
be possible automatically to reload these modules.  Unloading ALSA
sound driver modules:/sbin/alsa: 135: /sbin/alsa: cannot create
/var/run/alsa/modules-removed: Directory nonexistent  snd-usb-audio
snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-seq-midi
snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-rawmidi snd-pcm
snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device snd-page-alloc.
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/alsa': Permission denied
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ sudo alsa force-reload Unloading ALSA sound
driver modules: snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hda-codec-realtek
snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-seq-midi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep
snd-rawmidi snd-pcm snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-timer
snd-seq-device snd-page-alloc (failed: modules still loaded:
snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep
snd-pcm snd-timer snd-page-alloc). Loading ALSA sound driver modules:
snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-hdmi
snd-seq-midi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-rawmidi snd-pcm
snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device snd-page-alloc.
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -e alsa -e pulseaudio ii 
alsa-base                                                  
1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1                  ALSA driver configuration files ii  alsa-hda-dkms                                              
0.201210081115~precise1                 HDA driver in DKMS format. ii  alsa-utils                                                 
1.0.25-1ubuntu5.2                       Utilities for configuring and using ALSA ii  bluez-alsa                                             
4.98-2ubuntu7.2                         Bluetooth ALSA support ii  bluez-alsa:i386                                            
4.98-2ubuntu7.2                         Bluetooth ALSA support ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa                                         
0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1                      GStreamer plugin for ALSA ii  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio                                   
0.10.31-1ubuntu1.2                      GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio ii  pulseaudio                                             
1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4                       PulseAudio sound server ii 
pulseaudio-equalizer                                       
2.7.0.2-2~webupd8~oneiric3              PulseAudio Equalizer - LADSPA plugin graphical user interface ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth       
1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4                       Bluetooth module for
PulseAudio sound server ii  pulseaudio-module-gconf                   
1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4                       GConf module for PulseAudio
sound server ii  pulseaudio-module-x11                                
1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4                       X11 module for PulseAudio
sound server ii  pulseaudio-utils                                     
1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4                       Command line tools for the
PulseAudio sound server
```

The list of output devices is empty and there's no sound after running these still.

EDIT: new command attempt

```
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ speaker-test

speaker-test 1.0.25
Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$
```

EDIT 2

```
liliet@LilietNotebook:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: Property name not a string.
E: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: Property name not a string.
E: [pulseaudio] module-ladspa-sink.c: Master sink not found
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-ladspa-sink" (argument: "sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master= plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=3.6,3.3,3.3,3.6,3.0,3.6,3.0,3.6,3.0,3.3,3.0,4.3,4.0,3.3,3.0"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

Comment: install aptitude with  `sudo apt-get install aptitude` before running `aptitude --purge reinstall etc... `

Comment: ...well that should have been obvious *looks at self disapprovingly*  Thank you!

Comment: it did not help even after reboot )=

Comment: can you run a simple `speaker-test` (with no option)?

Comment: yes! added the result

Comment: I do not get how `aptitude` has any relation to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu defaults with pulseaudio. USB headphone is essentially a separate audiocard and it just get the "default" position.
Install `pavucontrol` application and use it to test and config your audio. Disable the one you do not need on the last tab. Set proper defaults.

With the problem you have uncovered, look here: [What is a "Failed to load module "module-ladspa-sink"" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325262/what-is-a-failed-to-load-module-module-ladspa-sink-error) You can safely delete all the config files mentioned there that reside in your home directory - pulseaudio runs perfectly on defaults.

Comment: thank you! i suspected something like this... let's see if I can use pavucontrol without asking more questions...

Comment: It freezes at the screen that says that connection to pulseaudio failed and suggests running 'start-pulseaudio-x11', which tells me that, again, connection failed.

Comment: By typing random commands from Internet without understanding what you do you have made something with your PC. Pulseaudio, the sound system, is not running. First of all, try running 'pulseaudio' from terminal and see if it shows some errors. Then, add this info here. Headphones likely have nothing to do with it, so plug them off for the time being.

Comment: done and done (i've long ago plugged off the headphones...)

Comment: Thank you! This helped! A warning to anyone who might want to use this post as a reference for their own troubleshooting: REBOOT THE COMPUTER AFTER YOU DID THAT. I got horrible white noise out of speakers for some reason after I took out the charger cable )= However, after reboot everything is fine! Thanks again!